# CSS background-size in Safari

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a background image (`background: url('...svg') no-repeat;`) which I force into the right size with `background-size: 100% 100%;`. This creates the desired effect and seemed to work great, until I looked at the page with Safari. Safari seems to ignore my `background-size` settings and use `background-size: contain;` instead (it centers the image though, so not exactly contain).

I found an other post on Stack Overflow which said that one has to use `-webkit-background-size` for Safari. That doesn't work either though.

You can see what I mean in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7mLzdto/). In Safari both divs will look the same.

Does anyone know how I get this working in Safari?

Comment: Have you used background-size:cover; . If not then try it.

Comment: background-size: cover; preserves the aspect-ratio, so doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with your Data URI. If you replace the `url()` link to a normal image link, the sizing on Safari should work like expected. The sizing will also work if you use a different data type in the URI (something besides an SVG).

Cheers,
Jeffrey

Comment: Hey Jeffrey, I only used a data URI in the fiddle for convenience sake. The actual homepage uses `url('path/to/background.svg')`. I'd prefer to get this working with an svg, since the div can get arbitrarily big.